# How do nominators get paid in the staking?

Tags: validator, transaction-fees, nominator

In the pallet-staking, the transaction fee is distributed between the treasury and author. I want to know that how validators and nominator are getting their reward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When producing a block the validator gets a reward.

- First the validator fee is subtracted. This is the fee the owner of the validator setup when launched the validator
- The remaining fee is distributed proportional to the amount staked by the nominators and the validator itself